# How to create wordpress theme custom page url

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

wordpress theme developers use it's theme hierarchy pages and urls rules like : category , single , archive and ... .
My question is :
How can I create pages for "User Login" , "User Register" , "User Profile" or some other pages and urls like theme for wordpress theme?

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways you could go about this. https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-create-custom-login-page-for-wordpress/ This article gives some examples and uses a a plugin I've seen as a popular solution for this "WP Forms"

If that does not appeal to you, you could always make a page template assigned to you "login" page, and then use an iFrame linked to your login url.

Hope that this helps! :)